# Dio Request lock and Unlock using Queued Interceptor flutter

Tags: flutter, token, interceptor, refresh-token, dio

I am trying to handle 401 using dio interceptor. Earlier dio supported Request Lock and unlock but now it doesn't it seems. I came to know that similar could be done using Queued Interceptor but I don't know how. Does anyone know how this can be done. Also, how to manage incase the refresh token itself expires.

Comment: do you work with jwt refresh token system or normal token?

Comment: I mostly work with jwt.

Comment: Locking will not be needed with Queued Interceptors, as it executes interceptors in order. Just make your interceptors extend from QueuedInterceptor instead of Interceptor. And if your refresh token expires, you should have a new Dio Exception. In my case, if refreshing fails, I just let the exception/error be thrown and handle it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

This may be if you use **InterceptorsWrapper** (Normal Interceptors)for dio.

```
Dio dio = Dio();
dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
  onRequest: (RequestOptions options) {
    // Interception logic before sending the request
    return options;
  },
  onResponse: (Response response) {
    // Interception logic after receiving the response
    return response;
  },
  onError: (DioError error) {
    // Interception logic for handling errors
    return error;
  },
));
```

This interceptor is best when you have no any await code insideInterceptors.

However if you are adding **token in Interceptors header** and which is **await** function or **any await function** you may need **QueuedInterceptorsWrapper**.
It's useful when you want to perform asynchronous operations inside the interceptor.

```
final Dio _dio = Dio()
_dio.interceptors.add(
      QueuedInterceptorsWrapper(
        onRequest: (RequestOptions requestOptions,
            RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
          print("Add token to header")
        },
        onError: (error, handler) async {
          print("error")
        },
      ),
);
```